# Jmeter: Issue with passing an value from Command line

Tags: jmeter

When I pass an integer value from command line -Jvalue = 100, Jmx script  reads teh value  if I use it in user defined variable like ${__P(value)} or ${__P(value,2)}

When I pass a string value -Jvalue=jmeter, JMX script does not take the value..

Can you pls help me on this?

Comment: What error message do you get with string values?

Comment: resolved now..Thank u

Comment: Please vote up on answers you found useful. If none of the answers were useful, please post how you solved it so it will be useful to others searching for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Remove spaces around `=`, it needs to be

```
value=100
```

or

```
value=jmeter
```

All the properties values passed via command line arguments or *user.properties* file are treated as strings.

Also if you set the same property twice, only last value will be considered.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on the ways of JMeter properties manipulation